# Show that the set $A:=\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0} \, | \, x^2 \geq 2 \}$ has no greatest lower bound in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I went over a few practice problems from my Real analysis class and encountered this statement:

> Show that the set $A:=~${$x \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}~|~x^2 \geq 2$} has no greatest lower bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I spent more a lot of time on it, because I couldn't make sense of the provided (overcomplicated) solution. Hence I tried to proove it another way. Here is my proof, I would really appreciate any comments and critics:

---

Let's assume that $y=\inf(A)$ is the infinum. We have 2 possibilites: $y \in A$ or $y \notin A$

**Case 1:** $y \in A \Rightarrow y^2 \geq 2$
There is no rational number $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ for which we have $q^2 =2$. Therefore we have that $y^2 > 2$.
Let $p=y - \frac{1}{n}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ be a lower bound. $y$ is the greatest lower bound, so we must have that $p < y$ and $p \notin A$. Let $y-\sqrt{2}$ be the distance between $y$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

$$p \in A \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n} \leq y - \sqrt{2} \Leftrightarrow n \geq \frac{1}{y-\sqrt{2}}$$

We have that $y-\sqrt{2} > 0$, so there are $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ for which this is the case. Hence $\exists p \in A$ with $p < y$, which contradicts the fact that $y=\inf(A)$.

**Case 2:** $y \notin A \Rightarrow y^2 < 2$
$y = \inf(A)$, so there can't be any greater lower bounds. Let's assume that $q = y + \frac{1}{n}$ was a lower bound with $q > y$. Let $\sqrt{2} - y$ be the distance between $\sqrt{2}$ and $y$. $q$ is a lower bound if and only if

$$ \frac{1}{n} < \sqrt{2} - y \Leftrightarrow n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-y} $$

If $y < 0 \Rightarrow 0 < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-y} < 1$ and $1 \leq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. 
If $0 \leq y < \sqrt{2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-y} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. 
Hence, we always find a lower bound greater than $y$ which contradicts the fact that $y = \inf (A)$.

In conlusion, the set $A$ has no greatest lower bound.

Comment: At this stage of the development, you probably want to prove this without mentioning $\sqrt{2}$.  (Of course the set has a greatest lower bound, but not a rational one.)

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes thank you, it was supposed to be "Let $p=y - \frac{1}{n}$". I changed it in the post.

Comment: @coudy The teaching assistant wrote an entire page of inequalties for case 1, which did not make a lot of sense to me. He also defined a lower bound $y - \frac{1}{n}$ but after that sth else. For Case 2, he only wrote: "obviously there are greater lower bounds for $n > \frac{\sqrt{2} + y}{2 - y^2}$ and that was it.

Comment: The question should be that $A$ has no greatest lower bound *in rationals*. This is equivalent to proving that $A$ has no least element and $\mathbb{Q} \setminus A$ has no largest element.

Answer (score 1):

If
$x^2>2$ then,
applying Newton's iteration,
if

$\begin{array}\\
y
&=\dfrac{x+\frac{2}{x}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+2}{2x}\\
\text{then}\\
y^2
&=\dfrac{(x^2+2)^2}{(2x)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{x^4+4x^2+4}{4x^2}\\
\text{so}\\
y^2-2
&=\dfrac{x^4+4x^2+4}{4x^2}-2\\
&=\dfrac{x^4-4x^2+4}{4x^2}\\
&=\dfrac{(x^2-2)^2}{4x^2}\\
&\gt 0\\
\text{and}\\
x-y
&=x-\dfrac{x+\frac{2}{x}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{x-\frac{2}{x}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2-2}{2x}\\
&\gt 0\\
\text{so}\\
y
&\lt x\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$y < x$
and
$y^2 > 2$
so $y$ is rational
if $x$ is rational
and
$x$ is not the smallest rational
such that $x^2 > 2$.

The nice thing about this proof
is that it works completely
in the rationals
and does not need
the concept of
$\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Should be slightly rearranged to cover "greatest lower bound".  Start with a lower bound and construct something larger which is still a lower bound.

Comment: You are right. I did least upper bound. I was confused because the statement said $x^2 \ge 2$.